# Keras ML library: how to do weight clipping after gradient updates? TensorFlow backend

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use Keras to implement part of an algorithm that requires weight clipping, i.e. limiting the weight values after a gradient update. I haven't found any solutions through web searches so far.

For background, this has to do with the WGANs algorithm:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.07875.pdf

If you look at algorithm 1 on page 8, you'll see the following:

[image]

I've highlighted the lines that I'm trying to implement in Keras: after computing a gradient to use to update the weights in the network, I want to make sure that all the weights are clipped between some values [-c, c] that I can set.

How could I go about doing this in Keras?

For reference I am using the TensorFlow backend. I don't mind digging into things and adding messy quick-fixes for now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While creating the optimizer object set param `clipvalue`. <s>It will do precisely what you want.</s>

```
# all parameter gradients will be clipped to
# a maximum value of 0.5 and
# a minimum value of -0.5.
rsmprop = RMSprop(clipvalue=0.5)
```

and then use this object to for model compiling

```
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=rsmprop)
```

For more reference check: [here](https://keras.io/optimizers/#parameters-common-to-all-keras-optimizers).

Also, I prefer to use `clipnorm` over `clipvalue` because with `clipnorm` the optimization remains stable. For example say you have 2 parameters and the gradients came out to be `[0.1, 3]`. By using `clipvalue` the gradients will become [0.1, 0.5] ie there are chances that the direction of steepest decent can get changed drastically. While `clipnorm` don't have similar problem as all the gradients will be appropriately scaled and the direction will be preserved and all the while ensuring the constraint on the magnitude of the gradient.

**Edit: The question asks weights clipping not gradient clipping:**

Gradiant clipping on weights is not part of keras code. But `maxnorm` on weights constraints is. Check [here](https://keras.io/constraints/).

Having said that it can be easily implemented. Here is a very small example:

```
from keras.constraints import Constraint
from keras import backend as K

class WeightClip(Constraint):
    '''Clips the weights incident to each hidden unit to be inside a range
    '''
    def __init__(self, c=2):
        self.c = c

    def __call__(self, p):
        return K.clip(p, -self.c, self.c)

    def get_config(self):
        return {'name': self.__class__.__name__,
                'c': self.c}

import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=100, W_constraint = WeightClip(2)))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')

X = np.random.random((1000,100))
Y = np.random.random((1000,1))

model.fit(X,Y)
```

I have tested the running of the above code, but not the validity of the constraints. You can do so by getting the model weights after training using `model.get_weights()` or `model.layers[idx].get_weights()` and checking whether its abiding the constraints.

Note: The constrain is not added to all the model weights .. but just to the weights of the specific layer its used and also `W_constraint` adds constrain to `W` param and `b_constraint` to `b` (bias) param

Comment: Thanks but this says -- 
# all parameter gradients will be clipped to
# a maximum value of 0.5 and
# a minimum value of -0.5.
-- does this not imply that it's the gradients, and not the weight values themselves, that are being clipped?

Comment: Sorry I was too quick to reply and didn't checked the clipping is on the weights. Will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: OK no problem your updated answer looks fantastic! Thanks buddy

Comment: I think for the [newest versions of keras](https://keras.io/constraints/), the kwarg is `kernel_constraint`.