# Keras Model Weights for some layers become all "NaNs"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training a triplet model similar to -[Keras model params are all "NaN"s after reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292212/keras-model-params-are-all-nans-after-reloading); except that this model is built over the inception_v3 model.

(I am using Keras with Tensorflow backend)

But after just 2 epochs the model weights turn out to be NaN. And when I try to extract learnt features by passing an Input Image the features are all 0.

Model Architecture-

def triplet_loss(x, ALPHA=0.2):

```
anchor, positive, negative = x                                      

pos_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, positive)), 1)
neg_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, negative)), 1)

basic_loss = tf.add(tf.subtract(pos_dist, neg_dist), ALPHA)         
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.maximum(basic_loss, 0.0), 0)               

return loss
```

class StyleNet():

```
def __init__(self, input_shape_x, input_shape_y, input_shape_z, n_classes, reg_lambda):

    self.input_shape_x = input_shape_x                              
    self.input_shape_y = input_shape_y                              
    self.input_shape_z = input_shape_z                              
    self.n_classes = n_classes                                      
    self.reg_lambda = reg_lambda                                    


def create_model(self):                                             

    anchor_example = Input(shape=(self.input_shape_x, self.input_shape_y, self.input_shape_z), name='input_1')
    positive_example = Input(shape=(self.input_shape_x, self.input_shape_y, self.input_shape_z), name='input_2')
    negative_example = Input(shape=(self.input_shape_x, self.input_shape_y, self.input_shape_z), name='input_3')

    input_image = Input(shape=(self.input_shape_x, self.input_shape_y, self.input_shape_z))

    base_inception = InceptionV3(input_tensor = input_image, input_shape=(self.input_shape_x, self.input_shape_y, self.input_shape_z), weights=None, include_top=False, pooling='avg')
    base_pool5 = base_inception.output                              

    ##############Adding the Bottleneck layer Here#######################################################
    bottleneck_layer = Dense(256, kernel_regularizer=l2(self.reg_lambda), name='bottleneck_layer')(base_pool5)
    bottleneck_norm = BatchNormalization(name='bottleneck_norm')(bottleneck_layer)
    bottleneck_relu = Activation('relu', name='bottleneck_relu')(bottleneck_norm)
    bottleneck_drop = Dropout(0.5)(bottleneck_relu)                 

    fin = Dense(self.n_classes)(bottleneck_drop)                    
    fin_norm = BatchNormalization(name='fin_norm')(fin)             
    fin_softmax = Activation('softmax')(fin_norm)                   
    ######################################################################################################

    ###########Triplet Model Which learns the embedding layer relu6####################
    self.triplet_model = Model(input_image, bottleneck_drop)        
    positive_embedding = self.triplet_model(positive_example)       
    negative_embedding = self.triplet_model(negative_example)       
    anchor_embedding = self.triplet_model(anchor_example)           
    ###########Triplet Model Which learns the embedding layer relu6####################

    adam_opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001, clipnorm = 1.0, amsgrad=False)

    #The Triplet Model which optimizes over the triplet loss.       
    loss = Lambda(triplet_loss, output_shape=(1,))([anchor_embedding, positive_embedding, negative_embedding])
    self.triplet_model_worker = Model(inputs=[anchor_example, positive_example, negative_example], outputs = loss)
    self.triplet_model_worker.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=adam_opt)

def fit_model(self, pathname='./models/'):                          
    if not os.path.exists(pathname):                                
        os.makedirs(pathname)                                       
    if not os.path.exists(pathname+'/weights'):                     
        os.makedirs(pathname+'/weights')                            
    if not os.path.exists(pathname+'/tb'):                          
        os.makedirs(pathname+'/tb')                                 
    filepath=pathname+"weights/{epoch:02d}.hdf5"                    
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=False, mode='auto')
    tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=pathname+'/tb', write_graph=True, write_images=True)
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint, tensorboard]                      

    #Parameter                                                              
    params = {'dim': (224, 224), 'batch_size':32, 'n_classes':11, 'n_channels':3, 'shuffle':True}

    #Datasets                                                               
    partition = pickle.load(open('../../../data/bam_2_partition_triplet.pkl', 'rb'))
    labels = pickle.load(open('../../../data/bam_2_labels_triplet.pkl', 'rb'))

    #Generators                                                             
    training_generator = DataGenerator(partition['train'], labels, **params)
    self.triplet_model_worker.fit_generator(generator = training_generator,  epochs = 60, use_multiprocessing=True, workers = 10, callbacks = callbacks_list, verbose = 1)
```

What is troublesome is as answered in the link above. Even after using ***clipnorm=1.0**** the gradients explode and the weights give out "nan" values.

Saving and loading the model, then printing the weights. The NaNs are clearly visible.
   Loading code:

```
m = load_model('/scratch/models_inception_stage2/yo/weights/02.hdf5', custom_objects={"tf":tf})

for layer in m.layers:                                                  
    weights = layer.get_weights()                                       
    print (weights)
```

Snippet for the printed weights

```
Here
[array([ 3.4517611e-04,  1.3431008e-03, -1.1081886e-03,  2.6104850e-04,
   -2.1620051e-04,  1.6816283e-03,  8.8927911e-05, -3.8964470e-04,
    1.7968584e-03,  1.0259283e-03,  5.0400384e-04, -3.6578919e-04,
   -1.1292399e-03,  1.1509922e-03,  3.2478449e-04, -3.6580343e-05,
   -4.4458261e-04,  4.8210021e-04, -9.5213606e-04, -6.4406055e-04,
    5.0959276e-04, -3.4098624e-04, -7.0486858e-05,  2.8134760e-04,
   -8.0100907e-04,  8.2962180e-04, -6.4140803e-04,  9.4872032e-04,
   -3.3409546e-05, -3.0277384e-04,  5.2237371e-04, -8.3427120e-04,
   -2.5856070e-04, -1.0346439e-03,  4.3354488e-05, -8.8099617e-04,
   -6.8233605e-04, -1.2386916e-04,  8.2019303e-04, -1.9070004e-03,
    1.5571159e-03, -3.4599879e-04,  6.2088901e-04, -8.4720332e-06,
    1.6024955e-04, -1.2059419e-03, -1.4946899e-04, -6.7080715e-04,
   -2.8154058e-05,  5.1517348e-04,  5.9993083e-05,  2.8555689e-04,
    3.9626448e-04, -5.1538437e-04,  1.9132573e-04,  1.1226863e-03,
    1.1591403e-03, -6.3404470e-04,  2.8910063e-04, -7.9366821e-04,
   -1.7228167e-04,  6.2899920e-04,  1.7438219e-04,  1.1385380e-04],
  dtype=float32), array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
   nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
   nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
   nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
   nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
  dtype=float32), array([0.50248814, 0.48732147, 0.64627343, 0.49432775, 0.45906776,
   0.5168214 , 0.8561428 , 0.7308014 , 0.5067555 , 0.516555  ,
   1.3287057 , 0.5746422 , 0.55597156, 1.0038179 , 0.9859771 ,
   0.6110601 , 0.7357226 , 0.6123694 , 0.90676117, 0.5439505 ,
   0.48629472, 0.5434108 , 0.4934845 , 0.5407317 , 0.6443982 ,
   1.0403991 , 0.48624724, 0.83786434, 0.72478205, 0.7294607 ,
   0.536994  , 0.38235992, 1.0484552 , 0.45833316, 0.48205158,
   0.48236838, 0.71035874, 0.9472658 , 0.78085536, 1.0207686 ,
   0.5089741 , 0.97984046, 0.86524594, 0.9828817 , 0.49027866,
   0.7367909 , 0.57438385, 0.5011991 , 0.47189236, 0.52376693,
   0.45648402, 0.40523565, 0.8375675 , 0.57908285, 0.6055632 ,
   1.0325785 , 0.5377976 , 0.47033092, 0.83586556, 1.2780553 ,
   0.503384  , 0.54509026, 0.5375585 , 0.6091993 ], dtype=float32)]
```

Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Have you tried increasing your learning rate?

Comment: No. I have not tried that. Although I am not sure, I may have tried with 0.0001.
Can increasing learning rate solve this problem? I donot understand how it would ?

Comment: There seems to be some numerical instability somewhere. Your learning rate coupled with low gradient could drive that too if your rate is pretty low. Which is why I was wondering if you tried higher learning rates!

Comment: I tried with 0.001 Learning rate. Same result.

Comment: from the high level, I do not see any problems with your network layout. But I do not have much knowledge of those specifics to comment on it. Does this happen with other optimizers as well? For example SGD?

Comment: I have just tried with adam. Would you recommend using SGD or some other optimizer here?

Comment: might be worth trying just to narrow down the problem either to some definition in the network or the loss.

Comment: Another interesting thing I noticed, while printing the weights / parameters for each layer that the NaNs occur only at the batch_norm layers.
What could this indicate?

See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53830547/batch-norm-layer-weights-parameters-turning-nans-during-training-of-a-siamese-ne

Comment: that is interesting! If the batchnorm layers are getting NaN, I would check your input. BatchNorm divides by the variance, so could it be that your variance is zero for those minibatches? This can happen if everything is one number!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I manually checked the input and printed the minibatch (size 32). The mini batches had different vectors.

For further inspection I ran the training process each iteration at a time. The total training size is ~0.12M images. The parameters for the batch_norm layer become NaN somewhere before the 1st epoch completes.

Are there any other reasons this could be happening?

Comment: I checked up on it too. And there is an epsilon defined on the batchnorm layer to make sure you do not have the case where variance goes to zero affects the result. Are you running the training on multiple GPUs?

Comment: I am using a single GPU. (Each minibatch is trained on a single GPU.)

Comment: Is there a chance that there is a numerical instability matter associated with BN in Keras or Tensorflow as earlier experienced in Caffe?

Link : BVLC/caffe#5136

Comment: Another discovery here is that the network learns NaNs for the batch_norm layers even when the batch_size = 1.
Isn't this strange? So would that mean there is some problem with the triplet_loss or the weights sharing?

Comment: batchnorm doesnt make sense when the batch size is 1 because as such there is no variance right? So the batch size should be greater than 1.
If you are using only one GPU, then it might not be down to the problem of data splitting unevenly between the GPUs causing the NaN. 
There is something else that I notice that I hadnt first noticed. Your layer one weights seem really low. This could be a reason why this is happening because your variance goes really really low. Are you freezing the parameters of your Inception net? And also, can you check removing the kernel regularizer?

Comment: So my current work is a 2 stage pipeline.
Stage 1 : Train via a 11 label cross-entropy loss. 
Stage 2 : Load the weights from Stage 1 and then Train the triplet model. 

P.S. - 1. The first Stage has no sharing of weights. A regular classification network.

Comment: m.create_model() ;                                                   
    m.triplet_model_worker.load_weights(./models_inception_stage1/yo/weights/20.hdf5', by_name=True);
    m.fit_model('./models_inception_stage2/');

Comment: sorry for the late response! Have been travelling for the holidays. Can you try the training by freezing the weights of the inception layers? That way you can train only the layers you add on top and increase the learning rate for it. Maybe that can help you see whether this is a reason why your network goes to Nan?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. Will try it out and get back.

I can understand, it's holiday season. Thank you. I am grateful for all your help.

Also there is a chance that there is something wrong with Keras itself.
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11927

Comment: thanks for sharing that link. Looks like Keras team has added this as a bug! In that case, hopefully, they can shed some light on what is actually going on outside our speculations :)